# Java equivalent to C's "ispunct()"

Tags: java

Is there an equivalent Java function that the same as the C99 Standard function 'ispunct()'?

http://linux.die.net/man/3/ispunct

The functions returns `true` if and only if the character is a punctuation mark.

Comment: It'd be nice, if you'd explain what this function does, or at least link to the documentation.

Comment: The question is not about C, but Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
if (Character.toString(myChar).matches("\\p{Punct}")) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this (from [this link](http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:java_ispunct:txt)):

```
public static boolean isPunct(final char c) {
    final int val = (int)c;
    return val >= 33 && val <= 47
    || val >= 58 && val <= 64
    || val >= 91 && val <= 96
    || val >= 123 && val <= 126;
}
```

Comment: Behaviour of `ispunct` in C is locale-specific, which this function is not.